# How to escape specific HTML tags in a string

Tags: html, xml, html-agility-pack

I have a requirement to escape a blacklist of HTML tags before displaying then in a web page. The reason for the selectivity is to allow for formatting to be retained (bod, italics, fonts, etc) but not any tags that will "break" the page (scripts, meta, etc).

After thinking about this for a while I came up with two approaches:

1. RegEx -- as almost everyone would tell you, using RegEx for manipulating HTML is a **bad idea**
2. HtmlAgilityPack

I figured that my best (and really only) solution was to load the string into **HtmlAgilityPack** and **recursively** loop through the child nodes. For each node I would check if it was on the specified blacklist. If it was, I would escape the opening (and closing if it existed) node, then process the `InnerHtml`. If it was not on the list, then output the node as is while still processing the `InnerHtml`.

So, given the following (very simple) source

```
The quick <b style='padding: 0 25em;'>brown</b> fox <b>jumped <i>over</i> the <meta http-equiv='refresh' /> moon</b>.
```

I need the following output

```
The quick <b style='padding: 0 25em;'>brown</b> fox <b>jumped <i>over</i> the &lt;meta http-equiv='refresh' /&gt; moon</b>.
```

After a lot of research, I have come across several concerns, questions, and roadblocks.

1. Is `HtmlAgilityPack` the best library to use for this requirement?
2. Is a recursive solution the only way? I though about using the `.Descendants()` method since that returns a flattened list of all the nodes via internal recursion but that results in repeated content. Using the above example, the `<i>over</i>` node is part of the `InnerHtml` for the second b node but then also becomes its own node in the Descendants collection.
3. I could be missing the proper methods or properties, but I cannot find a way to output **just** the opening and closing tags without including the InnerHtml. My use case for this is to output the opening tag (including all attributes) as an escaped string, output the recursively processed InnerHtml, then output the escaped closing tag. I guess I could construct my own output by using the different properties (Name, Id, Attributes, etc) but I would think this is already available.

As I see it, the method would look *something* like this

```
public string EscapeHtmlTags(string value, ICollection<string> tags) {
   var doc = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
   doc.LoadHtml(doc);

   if (tags.Contains(doc.DocumentNode.Name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
      // output opening tag as escaped string ????
      EscapeHtmlTags(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml, tags);
      // output closing tag as escaped string ????
   }
   else {
      // output opening tag as is ????
      EscapeHtmlTags(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml, tags);
      // output closing tag as is ????
   }
}
```

Of course I still need to add error handling, and probably handling the various NodeTypes differently, and probably add a StringBuilder instance to collect the output, and so on... I could even possible go the approach of cloning and replacing existing nodes in the document.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: I'm not a fan of regex in general, and especially not of parsing HTML using regex, but in this particular case I think it is possible to use it, because the existing html hierarchy isn't important at all, you basically just want to replace all `<` with `&lt` when not followed by any of the whitelisted tags.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I ended up following your suggestion and using RegEx. The limitations of controlling the output from HtmlAgilityPack was just too much. Feel free to repost as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Thanks. You can give yourself credit. I only agreed with one of the methods you already figured out yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this on back-end side, i.e. in PHP:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

This function supports list of allowed tags, which you can use.

Comment: Thank you MilanG but we are not a PHP shop. If the primary point of your response is processing this on the back-end, I was already heading in that direction. I am just trying to find out the best approach (i.e. tool) to use in .NET.